# How to delete a class from realm file

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My default Realm has several classes. I want to completely remove all references and delete all data for one of the classes. How can I do this? When I remove the class from my application, the class is still listed when I open the file in Realm Browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To completely remove a class from your Realm file you'll want to do two things:

1. Remove the class from your application.
2. Have [your migration block](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) call [`Migration.deleteData(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration10deleteDataFSSSb) to remove all references to the class from the Realm.

Comment: Excellent, that did it. Thank you!

Comment: That is not a solution. After you remove the class from the app, how can you refer to it with `DeletedClass.className()` to get it removed in `deleteData` method?

Comment: There’s no requirement that you call `className()` to access the class name. A string literal containing the class name works just fine.